# PlayFramework 2.5 + AspectJ (aspectjweaver)

Tags: java, playframework, aspectj, playframework-2.5

I've been trying for over few hours to set up AspectJ in play 2.5 project.
Tried in both dev and production modes, with sbt and activator with everything i could find on this topic - yet nothing.

Could someone provide me with directions or example project files which work?

My build.sbt:

```
name := "project"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, LauncherJarPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.8.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.16",
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.10",
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt"     % "1.8.10"
)

EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes

javaOptions += "-javaagent:~/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar"
fork := true
```

My plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

EDIT:
Apparently same configuration/project works on linux with cmd:

```
sbt "run 9000" -J-javaagent:/home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar -v
```

Works = @Aspect is detected and injected on compilation (dev mode).

On Windows 7 and 10, above (with path to aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar pointing at correct file) doesn't work (tested on different OSs.

Comment: Well, thanks for showing an example of a working solution. Maybe you rather want to present the command line you use on Windows which does not work plus any error messages you might possibly get. BTW, how do you compile your aspects? You know you have to use the AspectJ compiler, don't you? One more thing, if you use LTW _aspectjweaver.jar_ is all you need during runtime, it is a superset of _aspectjrt.jar_ which consequently you do not need.

Comment: Correction: You only need to compile aspects in native syntax with _ajc_. Because that is the syntax I use, I assumed you would do the same. But actually when only using annotation-based @AspectJ syntax, you can compile with a standard Java compiler and let the AspectJ weaving agent finish the "half-done" Java classes into real aspects.